# Extracting a string from a tuple in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to make a dictionary of sorts using tuples. The idea is to store a word along with its description in a tuple. The tuple then goes into a list. After that, I'm supposed to be able to look up the meaning of a word in the dictionary by typing the word I want a description of.

My problem is to extract only the description part of the tuple from the list and print only that based on what word the user wants to look up. I do have a function that seems to work for making the tuples and storing them in the list but I think that function also is wrong.

This is as far as I have been able to come:

```
def tuples():
    dictionary = []
    while True:
    print("\n--- Menu for dictionary ---\n Choose 1 to insert a word\n Choose 2 to lookup a word\n Choose 3 to quit\n")
    answer = input("Write your answer here: ")
    if answer == "1":
        insert(dictionary)
    elif answer == "2":
        lookup(dictionary)
    elif answer == "3":
        break
    else:
        print("\nTry again!\n")

def insert(dictionary):
    word = input("What word would you like to add: ")
    des = input("Type a description of that word: ")
    info = (word, des)
    dictionary.append(info)

def lookup(dictionary):
    word = input("What word do you want to lookup: ")
    place = dictionary.index(word)
    print("\nDescription of", word,":", dictionary[place], "\n")
```

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary without tuples?  If you use the word as the key, and the description as the value, wouldn't that solve your problem without the need for the tuple list, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, a dictionary is my next task. But this task was specifically to solve the problem using tuples :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the other answer, this example loops through the list of tuples examining the word part of the tuple to get to the description part.  It differs in a number of respects, but the most important difference is that it uses tuple unpacking versus subscripting to get the contents of the tuple. To illustrate the key concepts I left out the user input part.

Note: If the list of tuples was long enough, you would want to consider sorting it and using something like the the `bisect` standard library to more efficiently search it and update it.

Example:

```
dictionary = [("cat", "Four legs, scratches."), ("dog", "Four legs, wags."), ("gerbil", "Four legs, kangaroo-like.")]

def find_description(dictionary, search_term):
    # Note use of automatic tuple "unpacking"
    for word, description in dictionary:
        if word == search_term:
            print(f"Description of {word}: {description}")
            break
    else: # no-break
        print(f"Could not find {search_term} in dictionary.")

find_description(dictionary, "gerbil")
find_description(dictionary, "hamster")
```

Output:

```
Description of gerbil: Four legs, kangaroo-like.
Could not find hamster in dictionary.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are trying to do by modifying your lookup function
to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to search the dictionary list for the query. I got your example to work with the following modification to `lookup()`:

```
def lookup(dictionary):
    word = input("What word do you want to lookup: ")
    place = next((i for i, v in enumerate(dictionary) if v[0] == word), None)
    print("\nDescription of", word,":", dictionary[place][1], "\n")
```

If you are concerned with runtime I would recommend abstracting out the `(word, des)` tuple out to a class that could be [hashable](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2019/02/01/hashable-objects-must-be-immutable/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20make,__eq__()%20method) such that you can use a dictionary as your dictionary, utilizing the faster lookup. This also would solve the issue of duplicate entries.

Comment: I tried your code but I only get it to print the entire tuple. What I want is the program to find the tuple in the list containing the word I want to look up and then only print the second part of that tuple i.e the description part.